# JSON parse error, original data now in message fiel {:message=>"incompatible json object type=java

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

My logstash filter code catches incorrect data, can anyone help me with the correct syntax? it points to an error in the pipeline, no, there are multiple pipelines I'm working on, but I'm also in doubt about the syntax

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/tmp/wd/accounts/*.json"
    codec => "json"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}

filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
    }
}

output {
   elasticsearch {
     hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
     template => "/etc/logstash/templates/accounts-template.json"
     template_name =>["accounts-template.json"]
     template_overwrite => true
     index => "accounts-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
     user =>  "user"
     password => "password"
}
   stdout {codec => rubydebug}
  }
```

Comment: Could you please share the error ?